# React Native and Mediapipe ios framework compatible

Tags: react-native, ios-frameworks, glog, mediapipe

I created a MediaPipe ios framework
And I'm trying to integrate it into a React Native project
But the app crash in `Mutex::Lock()` without any information
I believe the reason is my framework and RN both use `glog`
How can I disable `glog` for one of them ? or any idea to fix it
Thanks for reading

[Xcode Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h70os.png)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation, Mutex loc() is associated with Metro Bundler dependency. Try doing `npx react-native start` this will start the Metro Bundler  before you do `npx react-native run-ios`

Comment: `npx react-native run-ios` starts the emulator; what if I'm trying to test the app on a device? I tried running `npx react-native start` before I press the Play button in Xcode, but am still seeing the Mutex lock error.